# conflict next-auth with react 18

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-install, next-auth

i get this error when installing next-auth with react 18

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: gito-auth@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"18.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.13.1 || ^17" from next-auth@3.29.3
npm ERR! node_modules/next-auth
npm ERR!   next-auth@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\mizzo\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\mizzo\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-04-27T14_07_48_165Z-debug-0.log
```

**is theres any solution to fix it without using --force flag ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here's how I solved this problem:**

First, what's happening: next-auth is looking for react@"^16.13.1 || ^17", but it is not finding it. Instead it is finding react@18.1.0, which is a newer version. For some reason doesn't like this newer version, and you are being notified (it is not a big deal, but they decided it was worth stopping your build).

**One solution:** forcibly install the specific version of react that next-auth wants:

npm install react@18.1.0
What this does is roll back your react version to a slightly older one that is compatible with next-auth. You won't notice any difference, and in future iterations, hopefully next-auth is updated, so this goes away.

**Another solution:** make a sweeping decision to not install any older version dependencies:

npm install xxxx --legacy-peer-deps
What this does is ignore old dependencies for this package. It is more comprehensive, and makes a lot of the decisions for you.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you have to downgrade react to be able to install next auth, I've tried it, I downgraded react to version 17.0.2 and now can install next auth. How to downgrade react as follows

```
remove new version

npm uninstall next react react-dom @types/react @types/react-dom 

install old version

npm install next@12.1.2 react@17.0.2 react-dom@17.0.2
npm install -D @types/react@17.0.2 @types/react-dom@17.0.2
```

I hope the error installing next auth has been resolved

Comment: i just searched and found that next-auth uses old version of react as you said but i dont need to downgrade all it wants is put --legacy-peer-deps flag simply it tells node to ignore any modules that are older version than i installed in my app

Comment: hahaha I encountered this error, because I was using version 18.0.0, a few hours later I created a new project, and the react version changed to 18.1.0, I tried to install next-auth and it worked. Good Job

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed by the developers. Try 'npm install --save next-auth' again, everything should work now.

Answer (score 0):

it seems errors never seem to die down :)

I was trying to install the react google login dependencies when I encountered  similar error. It means that versions
of packages are conflicting. They expect versions to be the same which is practically impossible.

To fix this error just run:

```
npm install xxxx --legacy-peer-deps
```

where `xxx` are your arguments :)